# Mongodb how to decrement but prevent negative value

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, atomic, acid

I’m having an issue with my inventory management app. I want it to be atomic, so there’s no gap between read, and write.

Here’s what I’ve found so far:

- findOneAndUpdate is atomic, so there won’t be a gap between read and write
- $inc is atomic, and allows me to increment/decrement values without knowing their values

However, I want to use $inc so it decrements in my example with the decrement value, or the document’s value if subtracting the decrement value would make it negative.

So if I have a document with value 5, and decrement with 4, set it to 1.

If I have the same document with value 5, and want to decrement with 6, set it to 0 (as opposed to -1 with default $inc behaviour).

Is this possible somehow in an atomic way?

Comment: I believe you are looking for the operator "min" - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/min/

Comment: You can also use Updates with Aggregation Pipeline to conditionally update.